How to route traffic via secondary IP address on same interface?
I have taken up helping to administrate a very old (15+ years) and somewhat neglected virtual web server that was set up using a single interface with two IP addresses. One of those is used for everything, and the other one is only supposed to be used for incoming SSH connections and nothing else.
The server was set up with Ubuntu, and I have managed to upgrade it to Ubuntu 24.02 successfully, along with all the packages that run on it. So it should be fairly up-to-date, but there might be arcane legacy configs lurking in any corner still.
Now, while setting up postfix SMTP on this server, I noticed I'm unable to configure it to send messages via the public IP, and after some swift debugging, I'm confident it's a routing issue.
The interface was set up so the IP_SSH is the primary IP, so it's now bound by kernel and I'm unsure how to fix this, as I'm not that well versed with interface config and routing especially.
Things that probably are helpful to understand my issue follow. I replaced IPs with placeholders IP_SSH, IP_PUBLIC, GATEWAY, IPv6 and SOURCERANGE, but I hope it should still be understandable. If you need more info, please ask.
Output of ip a:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ABC brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet IP_SSH/28 brd GATEWAY scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet IP_PUBLIC/28 brd GATEWAY scope global secondary eth0:0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 IPv6/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Output ip r:
default via OUTSIDE dev eth0 
SOURCERANGE/28 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src IP_SSH
OUTSIDE dev eth0 scope link 

Debugging:
Output of ip r g 142.251.179.26 (google mailserver, load-balanced, easy test candidate):
142.251.179.26 via OUTSIDE dev eth0 src IP_SSH uid 1001 
    cache 

Output of nc -vzs IP_PUBLIC -w 3  gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25
nc: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com (142.251.179.26) port 25 (tcp) timed out: Operation now in progress
nc: getaddrinfo: Address family for hostname not supported

Output of nc -vzs IP_SSH -w 3  gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25
Connection to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com (142.251.179.26) 25 port [tcp/smtp] succeeded!

I believe that "simply" swapping IP_SSH with IP_PUBLIC here would achieve my desired result, though I'm far from certain if that's actually correct and especially not about the correct way to achieve this, and meddling with this with my not-really-knowledge seems very risky to me:
default via OUTSIDE dev eth0 
SOURCERANGE/28 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src IP_PUBLIC
OUTSIDE dev eth0 scope link 

SOURCERANGE contains both IP_SSH and IP_PUBLIC
Is there a way to neatly change this? Ideally without having to take the server offline and risking SSH connectivity.
Update: Output of iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

I'm not a network guy and thus not too sure if this captures correctly what comments are asking for, but here goes:
Output of sudo tcpdump -vi any src host IP_PUBLIC and dst 142.251.179.27 while running nc -vzs IP_PUBLIC -w 3  142.251.179.27 25
tcpdump: data link type LINUX_SLL2
tcpdump: listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL2 (Linux cooked v2), snapshot length 262144 bytes
08:56:01.159952 eth0  Out IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 12126, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    HOSTNAME.44443 > pd-in-f27.1e100.net.smtp: Flags [S], cksum 0xfa64 (incorrect -> 0x0872), seq 3530529516, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 327818188 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
08:56:02.221936 eth0  Out IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 12127, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    HOSTNAME.44443 > pd-in-f27.1e100.net.smtp: Flags [S], cksum 0xfa64 (incorrect -> 0x044c), seq 3530529516, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 327819250 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
08:56:03.245951 eth0  Out IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 12128, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    HOSTNAME.44443 > pd-in-f27.1e100.net.smtp: Flags [S], cksum 0xfa64 (incorrect -> 0x004c), seq 3530529516, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 327820274 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0


Instead of using placeholders like IP_SSH and so on, and explaining what the correspondences between them are, use RFC5737 TEST-NET addresses to replace your public addresses. That might be reasonable to hide you from identification or attacks. As for private RFC1918 addresses, always show them as is; if your security depends on them being undisclosed, that's much bigger problem than the one you're asking about, and you absolutely should first resolve that and make your systems secure even if you give out all the IP addresses.

Also, this might be not only your firewall, but some external firewall (ISP's one, perhaps). To explore that, can you please hint on what happens if you try doing traffic capture on eth0 during these connection attempts? Do TCP SYNs to port 25 ever leave the interface?

@NikitaKipriyanov Honestly, sometimes I'd rather have placeholders personally than still-fake and still-useless IP addresses that only happen to be IETF-approved. There's no risk of the ip addr output being copypasted into some developer's default configuration, and at least a placeholder is obvious at a glance without having to remember which IP is the client again.

Well, it depends. Too much abstraction hinders understanding (that's why Feynman said he always invented concrete examples, "hairy balls", in mind when being told abstract things). In computing, where there's already an awful lot of abstraction, this matters.And, about uselessness I'm not sure: if you actually configure these addresses on an interface, it will work. Very useful when playing in the lab. I reckon it's possible to abuse these networks as additional private subnets and nobody will notice any problems.
